# wxpython control to map file data to fields

Tags: wxpython

I have a file with 2000 fields, Im planning to create a application that will display the fields names and the field value on a panel..

Right now, I create 2000 static text box and text control fields in my application to display the data but it takes lot of time to create those fields and render it on the panel..

Is there any suitable control that I can use for this scenario.

Comment: How about using a `ListBox` or a `Grid`?

Comment: Grid looks like a nice option.thanks

Comment: Is there any searchable GRID..I was unable to find in wxpython demo

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ObjectListView` extension which provides an object-oriented interface over the plain ListCtrl.

Adding a search function is trivial, just add a `wx.SearchCtrl` and bind its `wx.EVT_TEXT` to a function which sets the objects that contain only part of the text in the searchctrl. Here's an example

```
def on_search_box(self, evt):
    keyword = self.search_box.GetValue()
    filtered_objects = []
    for obj in objects:
       for field in obj:
         if keyword in field:
            filtered_objects.append(obj)
    self.olv.SetObjects(filtered_objects)
```